# Problemas com exbição de máscaras de entada em PartialViews - Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com problemas com as máscaras de entrada (bootstrap) em todas as telas. Achei interessante o seguinte: Todas as minhas Views que são retornadas em forma de "PartialView", as máscaras de entrada não funcionam. Para testes, quando eu crio uma View e um controlador que retorna uma View, tudo funciona corretamente. Isso evidencia claramente que o problema é causado pelo retorno em forma de PartialView do meu controller.

Tenho várias Views do CRUD que são abertas Em forma de modal a partir da minha Index. Elas só funcionam se o retorno for PartialView. Só que as mascáras de entrada não funcionam de jeito algum... Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteCepData")]
        [Route("cep-gerenciamento/editar-cep/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var cepViewModel = _cepAppService.GetByCepId(id);

            if (cepViewModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return PartialView(cepViewModel);
        }
```

```js
@using SistemaComercial.Domain.ValueObjects
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Cep.CepViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Editar CEP";
}

<div>
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-shadow">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="false">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center"> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div id="validationSummary" class="text-center">
                    <vc:summary />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CepId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="txtCep" asp-for="CepId" class="form-control" data-plugin="formatter" data-pattern="[[99999]]-[[999]]" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CepId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Endereco" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtEndereco" asp-for="Endereco" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Endereco" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Complemento" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input asp-for="Complemento" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Complemento" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <label asp-for="Bairro" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input asp-for="Bairro" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Bairro" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Cidade" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input id="txtDescricao" asp-for="Cidade" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Cidade" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="UF" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input asp-for="UF" class="form-control text-uppercase" maxlength="2" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="UF" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PadraoSistema" disabled />
                                <label asp-for="PadraoSistema"></label>
                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="PadraoSistema" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="btnSalvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Salvar </button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span title="Fechar" class="icon wb-close"></span> Fechar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    @*<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //allow validation framework to parse DOM
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
            });
        </script>*@
}
```

```js
//Campo da View Edit contendo a Máscara de Entrada de CEP
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CepId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="txtCep" asp-for="CepId" class="form-control" data-plugin="formatter" data-pattern="[[99999]]-[[999]]" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CepId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    // busca os elementos do atributo data-modal e o vincula ao evento click
    $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {
        // Abre a janela modal com o formulário solicitado 
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('table').on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e) {
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });

    $('#modalCep').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#contentModal').html('');
    });

    dataTablePrincipalLoad();

});

function openmodal(url) {
    // Faz uma requisição Get e carrega o formulário na janela modal
    $('#contentModal').load(url, function () {
        $('#modalCep').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        //Enviar o foco para campo Descrição
        $('#modalCep').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
            $("#txtCep").focus();   
        });
        // Vincula o evento submit
        bindForm(this);
    });
}
function bindForm(dialog) {
    // Vincula o formulário na janela modalcom o evento submit
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            // Realiza uma querisição ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    // Se a requisição for satisfatória, a página atual é recarregada
                    if (result.success) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                        window.location.reload(); //Ajuda na exclusao, atualizando o grid

                    } else {
                        $('#contentModal').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

function dataTablePrincipalLoad() {

    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').hide();
    var table = $("#dtPrincipal").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/cep-gerenciamento/getCeps',
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [3] },
            { className: "align-right", "targets": [0] },
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return data.substring(0, 5) + "-" + data.substring(5);
                }
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "cepId", "name": "Cep", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "endereco", "name": "endereco", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "complemento", "name": "complemento", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "bairro", "name": "bairro", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "cidade", "name": "cidade", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "uf", "name": "uf", "autoWidth": true },
            {

                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a btnEditar title="Editar" data-modal="" href="/cep-gerenciamento/editar-cep/' + full.cepId + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span></a> |' +
                        '<a title="Detalhes" data-modal="" href="/cep-gerenciamento/detalhes-cep/' + full.cepId + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span></a> |' +
                        '<a title="Excluir" data-modal="" href="/cep-gerenciamento/remover-cep/' + full.cepId + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span></a> |' +
                        '<a title="Histórico" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default clockpicker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pessoaHistory" data-original-title="Histórico"><span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span></a>'
                }
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        }

    });

    $('.search-input').on('keyup change', function () {
        var index = $(this).attr('data-column'),
            val = $(this).val();
        table.columns(index).search(val.trim()).draw();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa parte nao pode ficar dentro da partial view, pq `@section` nao funciona dentro dela:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    @*<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //allow validation framework to parse DOM
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
            });
        </script>*@
}
```

so colocar a @section dentro da view principal que resolve seu problema.

Um guia em ingles bem explicado [link aqui](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-with-ajax-and-razor-partial-views)

Comment: Pois é @HudsonPH... O Problema é que minha View EDIT já é a view principal... No meu Controller ela é retornada em forma de PartialView, pois assim minhas janelas Modals funcionam corretamente.

Comment: @JalberRomano o seu problema é entre o retorno do controller e o section, para testar  coloque o seu sricpt no _layout caso funcione o problema é a `@section`

Comment: Eu fiz vários testes @HudsonPH, inclusive os que sugeriu e não funcionou. Conforme vc sugeriu, poderia ser algum" problema no retorno da minha controller"... Atualizei o Post com o meu Script... todos os botões Create, Edit, Delete e Details fazem o uso do atributo data-modal-""... É que quando clicados, o JS aciona o evento do click e é feito um load na Janela modal de forma dinâmica... Há algum problema no carregamento, pois ele está deixando de setar as máscaras nesse momento.

Comment: Digo isso, pq quando crio uma view para não ser aberta de forma Modal, ela funciona corretamente, mesmo mesmo se eu colocar o bloco de section scripts... Vc tem ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: `@section` tem problem a com partian view, outros testes para fazer adicione `console.log("TEST");` no comeco de cada funcao e no lugar de `$(function () {` troque por `$(document).ready(function () {` caso o "TEST" apareca e o js nao funcione o seu path esta errado

Comment: No console, apareceram dois "TEST", o modal executou normalmente...

Comment: se funcionou entao o seu problem é nessa lınha `@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}` confira se o path esta correto ou use por extenso

Comment: Estou com dúvida sobre a função bindForm... Tem um if e else.... Eu coloquei um Console nos dois e ele não está caindo... Será que não é o request ajax? O path de RenderPartialAsync está correto..... Isso que me intriga.. Será que o problema não estaria no Bind?

Comment: Já se esgotaram todas as possibilidades... Você não gostaria de dar uma olhada no projeto via TeamViewer? Aí, se encontrássemos uma solução, poderíamos postar aqui para ajudar outras pessoas...

Comment: eu posso ver daqui umas 2h-3h

Comment: Sem problema... posso te aguardar. Obrigado cara 

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78800/discussion-between-jalber-romano-and-hudsonph).